# What is significance of abstraction from an end user perspective

Tags: oop, encapsulation, abstraction

Recently I was asked a question in an interview that even if we are using abstract classes or interfaces in our code the end-user, who is most probably be clicking buttons on UI, won't be exposed to inner functionality.
So even if we don't implement our logic using abstract classes or interfaces, assuming end-user don't have access to my code, he won't know how this is implemented internally.
So why do we use abstraction when eventually user won't get any details about the implementation. 
Is it just because of best practices or something else?

Comment: Because *you* are the one maintaining your code, not your end user. You do that for you and other programmers who may need to touch your code.

Comment: I think this is a question testing how you think outside the developer box. Best practices promote many sought after characteristics of a program, including maintainability, scalability, readability, etc. Some best practices are about conventions that in turn make room for compiler or runtime optimizations. Beside the developer and the *end user*, there are other stakeholders too. When a program is hard to read or maintain, it has a high cost of maintenance. Who pays for it? The end user, eventually. If a program is slow to refactor, the end user is affected eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tell the interviewer that abstraction leaks, that base classes are for standards not abstractions, and that the enormous mess he plans for me to clean won't be cheap, because every lazy employer allows programmers to make them. What is he offering me that I can't get elsewhere?

The guy who started StackOverflow wrote an article about the subject of abstraction. It would behoove you to read it and stop caring about selling yourself. Knowledge and science will sell you better than any academic rehearsal.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's about the code to be more maintainable and easily extendable.

This may be hard to understand on small projects, but on larger ones, it makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Interface is good when you want to expose just declaration. What is enough for build process.

Abstract object is used when there is some part of code mostly vendor private methods used for some special calls inaccessible due to protection level in extended object.